# WebService de spring boot siempre devuelve 404 en wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee, wildfly

Realicé un WebService con 2 métodos con spring boot y funcionan correctamente con eclipse y el tomcat embedido que trae spring boot. El problema es que al hacer el deploy en el servidor wildfly 17 e invocar dichos métodos siempre obtengo un 404 como respuesta.
Este es mi archivo pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>archivosDPAS</artifactId>
    <groupId>mx.wxyz.patron</groupId>
    <name>Spring Boot Data REST Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Data REST Sample</description>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <swagger-version>2.9.2</swagger-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>               
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Mi proyecto cuenta con la siguiente estructura de carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo que levanta el spring boot:

```
package paquete.archivosDPAS;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowCredentials(false).allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT").allowedHeaders("*")/*.maxAge(3600 * 24)*/;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Este archivo tiene la configuración de conexion a la base de datos:

```
package paquete.archivosDPAS.config;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
@Configuration
public class MultiDatasourceConfig{
    @Bean(name = "DSmysql")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.mysql")
    public DataSource masterDataSource(Environment env) {
        final String datasourceUrl = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.mysql.url");
        final String datasourceDriver = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.mysql.driverClassName");
        final String datasourceUsername = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.mysql.username");
        final String datasourcePassword = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.mysql.password");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(datasourceUsername).password(datasourcePassword)
                .url(datasourceUrl).driverClassName(datasourceDriver).build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "mysql")
    @Autowired
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("DSmysql") DataSource dsMaster) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
    }
}
```

Y este archivo contiene el punto de entrada de los webservice:

```
package paquete.archivosDPAS.controller;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import paquete.archivosDPAS.controller.jsonvo.Cfdi;
import paquete.archivosDPAS.controller.jsonvo.Tbldpa;
import paquete.archivosDPAS.serviceImpl.ArchivosDPASService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("archivosDPAS")
public class ArchivosDPASController{
    static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ArchivosDPASController.class);
    StringWriter sw =new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(sw); 
    @Autowired
    ArchivosDPASService archivosDPAS;
    @GetMapping("buscar")
    public Tbldpa buscar(String fecha_ini,String fecha_fin,String importe) throws Exception{
        Tbldpa tbldpa=new Tbldpa();
        try {
            List<Cfdi> tbldpasCfdis=archivosDPAS.buscar(fecha_ini, fecha_fin, importe);
            tbldpa.setTbldpas(tbldpasCfdis);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            LOG.error(sw.toString());
            throw e;
        }
        return tbldpa;
    }
    @GetMapping("descargaXML")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> descargaXML(String uuid) throws Exception {
        File archivo=null;
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        InputStreamResource resource=null;
        long tamano=0;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");
        Cfdi cfdi=archivosDPAS.buscar(uuid);
        String pathFile=cfdi.getRutaCFDI();
        try {
            String nombreSO=System.getProperty("os.name");
            //LOG.info(nombreSO);
            //LOG.info(pathFile);
            if (nombreSO.contains("Windows")) {
                pathFile="C:"+pathFile;
            } //else {
                //System.out.println("Unix");
            //} 
            archivo=new File(pathFile);
            if(archivo.exists()) {
                tamano=archivo.length();
                fis=new FileInputStream(archivo);
                resource = new InputStreamResource(fis);
            }else {
                String msg="No se pudo encontrar el archivo en: "+pathFile;
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                tamano=msg.getBytes().length;
                resource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            LOG.error(sw.toString());
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sw.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            tamano=sw.toString().getBytes().length;
            resource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
            throw e;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(tamano)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(resource);
    }
}
```

En local la aplicación funciona con las siguientes urls:

```
http://192.168.29.34:8080/archivosDPAS/buscar?fecha_ini=2021-09-29&fecha_fin=2021-10-06&importe=260
http://192.168.29.34:8080/archivosDPAS/descargaXML?uuid=AAA1CFD0-0E1C-4EBB-97B3-C6E8C04AA24D
```

Pero en produción he notado que hay que añadir otro archivosDPAS de la siguiente manera:

```
http://192.168.29.34:8080/archivosDPAS/archivosDPAS/buscar?fecha_ini=2021-09-29&fecha_fin=2021-10-06&importe=260
http://192.168.29.34:8080/archivosDPAS/archivosDPAS/descargaXML?uuid=AAA1CFD0-0E1C-4EBB-97B3-C6E8C04AA24D
```

Pero en todos los casos obtengo 404 en producción.

Tambien encontré que log del servidor manda la siguiente traza al hacer el deploy del war:

```
2022-01-13 18:15:51,341 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = archivosDPAS.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
2022-01-13 18:15:51,342 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 163) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/archivosDPAS' from server 'default-server'
2022-01-13 18:15:51,344 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 163) Unexpected state during contextDestroyed: no ConfigManager instance in current ServletContext but one is expected to exist.
2022-01-13 18:15:51,344 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 163) Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-01-13 18:15:51,344 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 163) Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-01-13 18:15:51,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment archivosDPAS (runtime-name: archivosDPAS.war) in 58ms
2022-01-13 18:15:51,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "archivosDPAS" (runtime-name: "archivosDPAS.war")
2022-01-13 18:15:51,415 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content/ee/0efedef158e4ab8a053cff5b3265cfaa552f32/content
2022-01-13 18:16:13,040 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content/ee/0efedef158e4ab8a053cff5b3265cfaa552f32/content
2022-01-13 18:16:13,042 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "archivosDPAS" (runtime-name: "archivosDPAS.war")
2022-01-13 18:16:14,173 INFO  [stdout] (Finalizer) log4j: Finalizing appender named [fileAppender].
2022-01-13 18:16:14,174 INFO  [stdout] (Finalizer) log4j: Finalizing appender named [console].
2022-01-13 18:16:14,637 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,638 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,638 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,639 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HttpHandlerAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,641 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 8.0)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,669 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = archivosDPAS.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
2022-01-13 18:16:14,694 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 184) Inicializando Mojarra 2.3.14.SP04 para el contexto '/archivosDPAS'
2022-01-13 18:16:15,002 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 184) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/archivosDPAS' for server 'default-server'
2022-01-13 18:16:15,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "archivosDPAS" (runtime-name : "archivosDPAS.war")
```

Aqui me llaman la atencion las lineas:

```
2022-01-13 18:16:14,637 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,638 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,638 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,639 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HttpHandlerAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2022-01-13 18:16:14,641 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
```

porque parececiera que no puede levantar spring, pero no se a que se deba ni como arreglarlo. ¿Alguien tendrá alguna idea de que pueda ser?

Comment: y ya intentaste poner tus logs en debug o trace como te dice tu mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en este archivo. Basicamente faltaba extender de `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

```
package paquete.archivosDPAS;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class RestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowCredentials(false).allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT").allowedHeaders("*")/*.maxAge(3600 * 24)*/;
            }
        };
    }
}
```